# youtube URL's not valid?

Tags: c#

Im using code like this to check if URL's are real and exist:

its working fine generally, but it's not working for youtube urls..
eg this valid url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4IBN5OAdZc

```
Utils.UrlExists(uri)

public static bool UrlExists(string url)
        {

            using (var client = new MyClient())
            {
                client.HeadOnly = true;
                // fine, no content downloaded
                try
                {
                    string s1 = client.DownloadString(url);
                    return true;
                }
                catch { return false; }
            }
        }

        class MyClient : WebClient
        {
            public bool HeadOnly { get; set; }
            protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
            {
                WebRequest req = base.GetWebRequest(address);
                if (HeadOnly && req.Method == "GET")
                {
                    req.Method = "HEAD";
                }
                return req;
            }
        }
```

Comment: youtube urls are case sensitive for some reason, this might help you

Comment: What does "Not Working" mean?  Your code runs and returns expected replies for me.

Comment: @John... looks like Eric was right. in lowercase it does not work. I didn't know that was even possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erics comment was the answer. If he puts an answer I'll mark it as correct. in the meantime I'll mark this as correct

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach:

Hit this URL with your C# code, and analyze the response:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<your ID>
```

You will be able to see the HTTP response of 200 when successful.

Try it in your browser; you'll see that good IDs give you content, others will return plaintext of "Private video" or "Invalid id".